# Utilisation des retraits au début des paragraphes

Tags: typographie, formatage

J'aimerais connaitre la règle concernant les retraits au début des paragraphes. J'ai recherché sur le net et tout le monde semble avoir sa propre règle...

Certains n'en mettent pas pour le premier paragraphe d'une section, certains en mettent à tous les paragraphes, d'autres n'en mettent pas du tout (j'ai regardé la mise en page de thèses).

Bref, y a-t-il une règle officielle à ce sujet? J'ai visité le site de l'Académie française mais rien à ce sujet.

Comment: Les thèses ne sont sans doute pas la meilleure référence en la matière (sauf une thèse en typographie peut-être...). Si je devais me forger une opinion à partir d'exemples, je choisirais plutôt [Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/).

Comment: @mouviciel merci pour ta suggestion je vais visiter ce site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comme tu t'en es rendu compte, il n'existe pas vraiment de consensus concernant les retraits de début de paragraphe. Je ne connais pas de règle officielle pour cette question, néanmoins:

- l'usage consistant à ne pas mettre d'alinéa au premier paragraphe d'une section, mais à en mettre au début des paragraphes suivants me semble généralement plutôt réservé aux textes anglais, et relativement peu employé en français (j'exclue ici l'usage des lettrines, qui n'appellent pas à une mise en retrait du texte). Le logiciel LaTeX fait d'ailleurs cette distinction (alinéa sur le premier paragraphe en anglais, mais pas en français) ;
- le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l’Imprimerie Nationale* semble préconiser la mise en retrait de tous les paragraphes, y compris le premier  (mais je n'ai pas accès à cet ouvrage et je me suis contenté de le lire [ici](http://www.framasoft.net/article2225.html#comments53529), ce serait à vérifier). C'est la pratique que je retrouve le plus dans les livres, il me semble ;
- pour ce qui des textes publiés sur Internet, je n'ai pas réussi à retrouver de sources; il me semble toutefois que les alinéas en début de paragraphe, de même que la justification du texte, sont sujets à débats. Je crois notamment avoir lu que l'un comme l'autre étaient déconseillés pour des raisons de lisibilité.

Au final, il s'agit souvent d'un choix de la personne responsable de la mise en page du document.
En cas de doute, pour un document à imprimer (rapport, thèse, ouvrage), nul ne devrait se voir reprocher, en français, de mettre un retrait à la première ligne de chaque paragraphe.

Comment: Merci. La règle consistant à mettre un retrait à chaque paragraphe rend à mon avis le résultat assez moche lorsque le texte contient des paragraphes d'une ligne, c'est pour ça que j'hésitais à utiliser cette règle.

Comment: @user3564358 Le problème dans ce cas, c’est le paragraphe d’une seule ligne. Tu ne peux pas regrouper plusieurs paragraphes ?

Comment: @Édouard je crois que je mélangeais "paragraphe" et "bloc de texte". Je traitais un paragraphe contenant plusieurs blocs séparés par un passage à la ligne (dont certains blocs ne contenaient qu'une ligne) comme plusieurs paragraphe, bien que ces blocs aient le même sens sémantique. J'ai donc corrigé ça en ne traitant plus chaque bloc comme un paragraphe.

Comment: @user3564358 C’est pas super clair. Quel type de document écris-tu ? Pourquoi tant de retours à la ligne ?

Comment: @Édouard un mémoire de stage. Sinon c'est simple: je traitais chaque bloc de texte comme un paragraphe à part entière, alors qu'ils parlaient du même sujet, donc j'ai regroupé de type de blocs en un paragraphe.

Answer (score 3):

Il suffit d'ouvrir n'importe quel livre en français (imprimé), on s'aperçoit que la plupart du temps la présentation des paragraphes ressemble à ça :

[image: French layout]

Contrairement aux traditions anglaises, il y a un retrait au début de chaque paragraphe (y compris le premier). En anglais la présentation la plus courante ressemblerait à ça :

[image: English layout]

Ces deux présentations conviennent bien aux textes traditionnels qui contiennent de longs paragraphes et la disposition compacte sans espace entre les paragraphes a permis de sauver des arbres.

Une autre solution, qui est celle employée le plus fréquemment sur le web consiste à remplacer les retraits par un espace vertical entre les paragraphes :

[image: Web layout]

Pour tout document qui contient des images, diagrammes ou équations entre les lignes (par exemple, un mémoire scientifique), ou qui est susceptible de contenir des paragraphes très courts, opter pour cette dernière présentation peut être un choix judicieux.

---

Note : les exemples ont été crées avec *luaLateX*, `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{french}`, `usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{english}`, et `\usepackage{parskip}` pour le dernier.

Comment: Merci j'ai en effet opté pour la dernière solution